# Loss of details after baking normals, why?

Tags: normals

[image]
I used the high poly mesh on the right and baked its normals on a low poly mesh, resulting in the model on the left. Despite the decent looking there was a big loss of details, which I can't fix by increasing the strenght of the normal map. Is it something with the Ray distance of the baking process or else?